# Excel vba - ADO inner join on data tables

Tags: vba, excel, ado

I have two data tables in excel that I wish to join into a single set in my vba code. I have identified the ADO connector as the best way to do this, however using the query below, I get the following error

"Run time error -2147217904

No value given for one or more required parameters"

```
SELECT components.[name], InputData.Datatype 
FROM [Rules$A5:F30] components 
INNER JOIN [Rules$O5:R17] InputData ON components.[name] = InputData.[name]  
WHERE components.RowId = 0 GROUP BY components.[name], InputData.Datatype
```

**EDIT:** The full code:

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim dataRows As Integer

strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
& ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon

strsql = "SELECT components.[name], InputData.Datatype " _
            + " FROM [" + GetTableAddress("componentTable") _
            + "] components INNER JOIN [" + GetTableAddress("DataLocations") + "] InputData" _
            + " ON components.[name] = InputData.[name] " _
            + " WHERE components.RowId = " + CStr(RowId) + " GROUP BY components.[name], InputData.Datatype"
rs.Open strsql, cn
If Not rs.EOF Then
    dataRows = rs.GetRows
```

and the GetTableAddress function

```
Private Function GetTableAddress(tableName)
Dim oSh As Worksheet
Dim oLo As ListObject

For Each oSh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each oLo In oSh.ListObjects
        If oLo.Name = tableName Then
            GetTableAddress = Replace(oSh.ListObjects(tableName).Range.AddressLocal, "$", "")
            GetTableAddress = oSh.Name + "$" + GetTableAddress
        End If
    Next
Next
```

End Function

Comment: Can you post the complete Code?

Comment: A very common reason for the 'No value given for one or more required parameters' is because of a syntax error specifically field names. Check that your field names are correct that you're using.

Comment: Uploaded the full code, the error occurs on the rs.Open method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both data sets are in Excel, you should use `vLookup` to create the final table.  It'll be easier for you and the benefit is that you can use syntax that you're already familiar with.

`vLookup` is essentially a table join.  You can even use it with `Application.WorksheetFunctions` if you wish to do it that way.

Also, `RecordSet.GetRows` can return an array.  You should probably use `CInt(rs.GetString)` if you're not expecting more than one value to be returned.