# Merging Datasets (Right Join) in VBA

Tags: vba

I'm in the process of creating a VBA script where I import two files into separate worksheets. Sheet 1's data includes masked account numbers, actual account numbers, account type and sub-account type. Sheet 2 includes the account number, account type, sub-account type and other columns that are important. What I need to do is merge sheet 1 with sheet 2 so that Sheet 2 will also include the masked account numbers (after the merge I will delete the account numbers and just keep the masked account numbers). Below is an example of what my datasets look like:
[image]

I've been doing this process in R with ease, I can simply just merge the datasets with a right_join function but now I need to replicate this process using VBA. I'm trying to search how to merge worksheets (datasets) but what I've found so far are examples of merging substrings which is not what I want. I believe I can do this with a nested vlookup but I was hoping to find a better way to do this in VBA. Any advice and or literature that would help me better understand how to create a script to merge the data would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Using worksheet functions, you can do this with `index(match())`, or if you rearrange your data to put the masked account number in a column after your account number in dataset 1, then a `vlookup()` will do the job. Unlike R or Python Pandas dataframes or a sql database, VBA doesn't have set based logic built into it, so it would solve through  iterating rows and looking up values. Alternatively, there is the ADODB library that you can reference, save a copy of your workbook to your drive, make a connection to it as if it were a database, and submit SQL against it. That would be overkill.

Comment: did you check PowerQuery?

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful info! I'll give the ADODB a read through.

Comment: You don't need to save a copy of the file in order to use ADO - as long as the file has been saved you can use the open copy as the source.  Eg see - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25290988/excel-vba-ado-inner-join-on-data-tables